# Syntax error or access violation Exception when trying to send JSON Data to Server

Tags: c#, .net, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I try to send a JSON data to a server using c#.
this is my code for posting data:

```
 private static string PostJSONData(string JSONdata, Uri url)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(JSONdata);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

my JSON data is like this :

```
{"Key":"auth_token","Value":""},
{"Key":"request_id","Value":"14104"},
{"Key":"_number","Value":"TAQ422924"},
{"Key":"Customer","Value":"Some Customer"},
{"Key":"first_date","Value":"2014-10-24T15:52:21"}]
```

when I try to send data, at line

```
var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

there is an error with this description

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) ) LIMIT 1' at line 1' in
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web16/web/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web16/web/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement-execute(Array
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web16/web/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(320):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo-_execute(Array)
>   .
>   .
>   .

whats this error for??? Its from a php page , I dont use any php page.

Comment: It's a server-side error. You JSON data is delivered to server, but server is not able to save it in MySQL

Comment: @JesseJames : oh, Fine. thats right. thanks Jesse.

Answer (score 0):

ContentType for json is "application/json" and not "text/json". The server may be treating you data as text rather than json.
You json data is also missing the leading square bracket '['